# Find the norm of a linear combination of vectors, given their norms

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors

If a and b are vectors such that $\|a\| = 4$, $\|b\| = 5$, and $\|a + b\| = 7$, then find     $\|2a-3b\|$.

So I first squared both sides and then got $ab = -44$. What do I do now?

Comment: Both sides of what?

Comment: also ab=-44 doesn't make sense. a and b are not numbers.

Comment: I did ||a + b||^2 = 49. That's how I got ab = -44

Comment: @DavidP I wonder why you deleted your answer...

Comment: @TZakrevskiy Was so long ago. Occasionally, rarely, i go through my answers and for some old ones that receive no attention i zap

Answer (score -1):

First compute A=angle between a and b using law of cosines $$\Vert a+b\Vert^2=\Vert a\Vert^2 +\Vert b\Vert^2 + 2\Vert a\Vert \Vert b\Vert cos(a,b)$$
 7x7 =4x4 + 5x5 + 2x4x5 cosA  ,
  cosA=1/5  ,

Norm of $$\Vert a-b\Vert^2=\Vert a\Vert^2 +\Vert b\Vert^2 - 2\Vert(a)\Vert b\Vert cos(a,b)$$
$$\Vert(a-b)\Vert^2 =16 +25 -2.4.5.1/5=33$$
Checking $$ 4 \Vert a\Vert \Vert b\Vert=\Vert a+b\Vert^2 -\Vert a-b\Vert^2$$
  4x4x5x1/5=16=49-33=16  ,   it's OK

Again use  law of cosines $$\Vert 2a +(-3b)\Vert^2 =\Vert2a\Vert^2 + \Vert 3b\Vert^2 -2\Vert 2a\Vert.\Vert3b\Vert cos A$$ 
$$\Vert 2a +(-3b)\Vert^2=4.16 + 9.25 -2.8.15.1/5 $$
$$\Vert 2a -3b \Vert^2 =241$$ , $$\Vert (2a -3b)\Vert=15.52$$

Comment: Please use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Also, it would be better to write formulas analytically before doing numerical applications, and to tell which theorem/formula is used.