# Vector Dot Product Problem

Tags: vectors

If $a$ and $b$ are vectors such that $|a| = 4$, $|b| = 5$, and $|a + b| = 7$, then find $|2a - 3b|$.

I've tried squaring $|2a - 3b|$ to get $2a$ • $2a$ + $4a$ • $-6b$ + $-3b$ • $-3b$, but now I'm stuck.

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/939412/265466, although that question has one downvoted answer and two deleted ones.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, $(a,a)=16, (b,b)=25$, so $49=(a+b,a+b)=16 + 2(a,b) + 25$, whence $(a,b)=4$. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

**hint**: $|2a-3b|^2 = 4|a|^2 - 12\langle a,b\rangle + 9|b|^2 = 4|a|^2 - 12\left(\dfrac{|a+b|^2 - |a|^2-|b|^2}{2}\right) + 9|b|^2$